# Ubuntu reboot repeatedly

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a `Ubuntu 10.04 LTS` in a VirtualBox.

Running `fsck -n` indicates some orphan nodes exist in the root file system and I try to fix it with following actions:

```
1) edit /etc/default/rcS and set FSCKFIX=yes  
2) touch /forcefsck  
3) reboot
```

The system reboots repeatedly with following error messages:

```
fsck terminated with status 3  
mountall main process terminated with status 4
```

Any help?

Comment: This belongs to AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

On the next reboot, add `init=/bin/sh` to your kernel command line, fix the problem, `sync` and `umount -oremount,readonly` any mounted filesystems that you can, and then `exit`.

Comment: The server reboot AUTOMATICALLY after print error messages before any shell prompt showing :-(

Comment: @Smartkid, you need to add that `init=/bin/sh` to your _kernel_ command line, through grub. Hit `e` to `e`dit the command line, add `init=/bin/sh`, then `^X` to boot the edited kernel command line.